# Plastic tries to replace old version, but on a drive that doesn't exist

Tags: installation, plasticscm

I'm trying to install the newest version of Plastic after deleting every trace of the old version I could find. Apparently the old version was on a drive that no longer exists. My best guess is that it was a drive that PowerISO had created.

PowerISO was installed by My PC repair guy, and I don't even know what it does, so I have no idea how Plastic was installed on it (assuming it was).

When I try to install, I get the first error (attached image), and when I press ok,I get the second one.

I've exhsusted every lead I can think of and at this point im time sensitively desperate to get Plastic working again so we can meet our game demo's deadline.

I tried putting what chat gpt suggested into the command line and it didn't work. I tried making a new drive with power iso but I couldn't get that to work either.

Does anybody have any ideas for what I can try?

Thanks

Comment: You reference an "attached image" but it isn't clear what this refers to. Did you intend to attach a bitmap of some sort? Does this refer to the nature of the error message? Suggestion: provide a bit more detail.

Comment: It just says that there's an error writing file, and then it says the directory. The next error says that a previous version of plastic has been detected (On a drive that no longer exists) and if I replace it, all configuration parameters will be kept. It seems to want to install to this drive but it doesn't exist. So I re-installef powerISO and created the drive. I just don't know how to give that drive actual space. Do you hsve any thoughts or ideas based on all of this? Thank you so much for the reply. I've exhausted every lead I could find.